# Using React JS CDN and publishing to productions questions

Tags: reactjs, hosting, qliksense

I'm using ReactJS CDN to build a web app. I am thinking of hosting it in a qliksense server that acts as a web server. The code runs fine without any issues and the users can access the app with the URL.

I have a few questions before I go into production.

1. I would like to know the cons of doing it this way.
2. Are there any factors that I should consider?
3. How can I minify the code?

Below is an outline structure of my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">
</script>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5.0.2/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.15.7/babel.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/babel" src="AppPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="App.js"></script>
   
    <link id="u-theme-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    <link id="u-page-google-font" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i">
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
function App(){

    const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);
  
    

    React.useEffect(()=> {
    //Do Something
    //setState(object)
    },[])
  
       
   return (
        <div id="appcontainer">
   {state.errorMessage !== null ? 
   <div> 
   <h6>{state.errorMessage}</h6>
   <h6>Refresh page or Contact support </h6>
   </div>
   : state.app ?
     <Box> <AppPage/> </Box> : null}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

AppPage.js

```
function AppPage(){

    
       
   return (
  <h1>hello</h1>
   
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only cons I can think of is the possibility that the end users might not have access to the CDN. If you are behind corporate proxy/firewall and for some reason the CDN is blocked then the mashup will not work.

I'm right assuming that you are developing inside the Qlik Dev Hub? If this is the case then in order to minify the code you'll have to download the code minify it (using webpack for example) and then re-upload it back to Qlik

Our web developers are actually developing mashups outside Qlik - developing on `localhost` and establishing connection with Qlik directly. Once they are happy with the result they minify it and upload it. So their development is done completely outside Dev Hub. The downside here is that a bit more work is needed to set the authentication because when developing inside the Dev Hub the authentication is already made.

Comment: yes this is a qilk mashup build on dev-hub using the capability api, as the authentication factor is handled by qlik and hosting can be done in qlik sense. The users are able to access the test app when using within the network.

Could you send an example to minify it, please?

Comment: sorry but im not a react guy

Comment: no worries, thanks